# Ice Cream Sandwich email app on Droid RAZR won't autofill all contacts

Tags: contacts, email, motorola-droid-razr

Why won't the Ice Cream Sandwich email app on Droid RAZR autofill all contacts? It works fine with Gmail but only for some contacts in the standard email app.